# Is the word, ‘nerdocracy’ just a nonce word, or becoming current?

Tags: contemporary-english, nonce-words

I was drawn to the word, ‘nerdocracy’ appearing in an article in New York Times’ TV Watch section under the title, “Start-Ups and Upstarts.” It reads;

> “There is a relatively new social order disrupting the peace, a **Palo
>   Alto nerdocracy** ruled by boy billionaires and Internet upstarts.
>   “Silicon Valley,” a new and very funny HBO series that begins Sunday,
>   taps into the foibles and pretensions world.”
>    [- Source](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/04/04/arts/television/nerds-get-their-due-on-silicon-valley-and-veep.html?src=dayp)

I’ve seen the word, “(Palo Alto) nerdocracy” for the first time. It must be a portmanteau of nerd+cracy as same as ‘democracy,’'bureaucracy' and ‘meritocracy,’ and I can guess what it means.

However, none of CED, OED and online English dictionaries carries this word, nor Google Ngram covers ‘nerdocracy.’

Is ‘nerdocracy’ a just one-off journalism coinage, or getting current recently?

Comment: It's just a nonce word, but it's understandable. If it's still around in 20 years, we'll talk about "current".

Comment: A nonce and future thing.

Comment: `-ocracy` has been highly productive all the way back to its Ancient Greek origins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nerdocracy

The Rule by Nerds that is replacing the old forms of rule with the rise of comic book nerds, LOTR nerds, Doctor Who nerds, Harry Potter Nerds, Star Trek Nerds, Star Wars Nerds, Renaissance Festival nerds, D&D nerds, science nerds (etc.) as evidenced by massive box office showings for superhero, science fiction, and other nerd-based movies, as well as shows like Big Bang Theory, and the unlikely celebrity of persons on the order of Bill Gates and Stephen Hawking.
The whole high school social complex has been upended by the emerging Nerdocracy.

The Nerdocracy has subsumed Hollywood, and will soon envelop our entire culture.

Source: Urban Dic.

I think that this neologism is here to stay.